# I have a disk that Linux sees with a perfectly fine GPT with one NTFS partition, but Win10 says the entire disk is uninitialized

Tags: gpt, partition-recovery

In Win10 I tried to convert from MBR to GPT using the "non-destructive" gptgen tool.  It flubbed the whole thing and Win10 said the disk was write protected and I couldn't use it, etc.

So I brought it to my Linux box and used gdisk. gdisk IDed a few issues that I then fixed with gdisk. So now gdisk says the disk has a protective MBR and GPT and it uses GPT. gdisk v command says no problems detected. gdisk p command shows 1 NTFS partition. gparted shows the 1 NTFS partition with no complaints or warnings. I can mount the NTFS partition and see all the files.

But when I return the disk to my Win10 box it says I must initialize the disk to use it and offers to init with GPT or MSDOS.  Of course I press cancel ASAP.  Bring it back to my Linux box and the disk is perfectly fine with the 1 NTFS partition.

Does anyone know why Win10 cannot interpret this disk's GPT table? Does the protective MBR need to go or something like that?

Here's the gdisk output when it opens:

```
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.3

Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: present

Found valid GPT with protective MBR; using GPT.
```

gdisk v command output:

```
Command (? for help): v

No problems found. 2679836777 free sectors (1.2 TiB) available in 2
segments, the largest of which is 2679629963 (1.2 TiB) in size.
```

gdisk p command output:

```
Command (? for help): p
Disk /dev/sdc: 3907029164 sectors, 1.8 TiB
Model: External USB 3.0
Sector size (logical/physical): 512/512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): C67971C4-E465-4186-893C-7197A1DABB31
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
Main partition table begins at sector 2 and ends at sector 33
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 3907029130
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
Total free space is 2679836777 sectors (1.2 TiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1          206848      1227399167   585.2 GiB   0700  WD
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that Win10 and / or Disk Management caches up info about a disk and even saves it across reboots and does not rescan that disk for more current info.  Related to this answer here: https://superuser.com/a/1515306/129638

The disk was, indeed, fine. If I brought the disk to another Win10 box that had not been attached to this disk before then it saw this disk's GPT partition table and partitions just fine.

I was not able to offline and online the disk as the other answer suggests because it already came up as offline.  Since I didn't really need to use this disk on that Win10 box that was rejecting the disk my problem was solved when I realized that other Win10 boxes accessed the disk just fine.